# How to implement recursive function to simplify polynomial terms with sorted tuple list?

Tags: list, tuples, ocaml

I'm trying to implement a function to add like terms of a sorted list of tuples (first number represents polynomial's constant, the second represents the power). I'm an ocaml noob and don't really know what I'm doing wrong or how to do this correctly.

I tried to write it, but it doesn't work
https://gyazo.com/d37bb66d0e6813537c34225b6d4048d0

```
let rec simp list = 
    match list with 
    | (a,b)::(c,d)::remainder where b == d -> (a+c,b)::simp(remainder)
    | (a,b)::(c,d)::remainder where b != d -> (a,b)::(c,d)::simp(remainder)
    | _ -> list;;
```

This should combine all the terms with the same second value and just return one tuple with their first values added to the new list. ie: [(3,2);(4,2)] -> [(7,2)].

Comment: Hi, would you please write the error message you're getting directly in your question, instead of a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the `where` keyword - there is [ocaml-where](https://github.com/hausdorff/ocaml-where) which provides it, but it seems to be doing something different than what you are expecting. As such, the syntax is just wrong, and `where` is unexpected.

You probably meant `when` instead of `where`.

Comment: Yes, the problem was indeed that i was using when instead of where. I also had the order of the sorting backwards. Instead of sorting by the second element of the tuple, I reversed the tuple elements to be (power, constant). Now it works. Thanks man. :)